# How to add view dynamically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have a listview with footer in an activity. What I want to do is adding a textview to footer programmatically.

There are **Activity.java**, **Activity.xml**, **footer.xml**

Part of Activty.java's onCreate() method:

```
      LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)View.inflate(this, R.layout.footer, null);
      TextView tv = new TextView(this);
      tv.setText("added text");
      tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      layout.addView(tv);

      View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.refer_footer, null, false);
      listView.addFooterView(footer);

      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Activity.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/referList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

footer.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</LinearLayout>
```

But I can't found added textview in app. Someone please help.

Comment: you are not using this `LinearLayout layout` object, and the `footer.xml` you posted is irrelevant since you are calling `listView.addFooterView(footer);` with this `R.layout.refer_footer` layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a TextView instance and add it to your ListView adapter.

```
 ListView listView = .. //create your list, or inflate it from xml...
 TextView footerView = new TextView(activity.getApplicationContext());
 listView.addFooterView(footerView);
 listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```